# Worksheet event not working when connected to the internet

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("O6")) Is Nothing Then
    If Len(Cells(6, 15)) >= 1 Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "kko"
    End If
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("O9")) Is Nothing Then
    If Len(Cells(9, 15)) >= 1 Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "kko2"
    End If
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("f4")) Is Nothing Then
    If (Range("f4") = Range("g4")) Then
        Range("G9").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("F6").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Range("G11").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("G6").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

The Excel file crashes when connected to the internet. I am new to the VBA and I need help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `Sub kko` and `Sub kko2` in your workbook code (where you keep this code).

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Select Case Target.Address
    Case "$O$6"
        If Len(Target) >= 1 Then
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "kko"
        End If

    Case "$O$9"
        If Len(Target) >= 1 Then
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "kko2"
        End If

    Case "$F$4"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Value = Range("G4").Value Then
            Range("F6").Value = Range("G9").Value
            Range("G6").Value = Range("G11").Value
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the names "O6" - as in the letter O and 6? as a named range?

Or are you trying to capture when someone clicks on .range("O6")?

If you just want to capture when the user clicks on .range("O6") then you don't need to use the intersect function.  Try using simpler logic like this.

```
If Target.Address = "$O$6" And Len(Cells(6, 15)) >= 1  Then
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "kko"
End If
```

As for not working when you are connected to the internet - that sounds like some kind of memory problem.  Are your functions "kko" and "kko2" really memory intensive?